# SQL: Copy all tables with same headings into one table

Tags: mysql, sql

**DB NAME : car_price**

**TABLES Names**

list_1
list_2
list_3
list_4

**LIST_1**

```
car_name   price      owner

benz        100$     mark
safari      1000$    james
```

**LIST_2**

```
car_name   price      owner

TVS          100$     crick
apache       400$     watson
```

**LIST_3**

```
car_name   price      owner

cbz          1000$     leo
unicorn      1600$     brick
```

**WHAY I WANT TO DO IS**

i want to copy all these to only one table, so that the new table looks like

**NEW_TABLE**

```
car_name   price      owner

benz        100$     mark
safari      1000$    james
TVS          100$     crick
apache       400$     watson
cbz          1000$     leo
unicorn      1600$     brick
```

hope you guys can easily help me...
waiting...

## Update

Now I want to change the query so that I copies all rows from other tables into list_3 table, so that LIST_3 table looks like

**LIST_3**

```
car_name   price      owner

benz        100$     mark
safari      1000$    james
TVS          100$     crick
apache       400$     watson
cbz          1000$     leo
unicorn      1600$     brick
```

Comment: `INSERT .. SELECT ... UNION`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by executing following statement

```
INSERT INTO `NEW_TABLE`
SELECT *
FROM `list_1`
UNION
SELECT *
FROM `list_2`
UNION
SELECT *
FROM `list_3`
```

#### Update

Following query will work for your updated question.

```
INSERT INTO `list_3`
SELECT *
FROM `list_1`
UNION
SELECT *
FROM `list_2`
```

Comment: @PradeepPati those backticks are intentional.

Comment: thank :) it showed me an error 
` Duplicate entry 'benz' for key 'car_name' `

Comment: I've updated the answer and also your question to keep old requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You should either use `UNION` or `UNION ALL`. If there are duplicate rows in your list_1, list_2, list_3 tables and you want to keep them in the new table, use `UNION ALL`. If you want the duplicates to be removed, use `UNION`.

```
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE
    SELECT * FROM LIST_1
UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM LIST_2
UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM LIST_3
```

or

```
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE
    SELECT * FROM LIST_1
UNION
    SELECT * FROM LIST_2
UNION
    SELECT * FROM LIST_3
```

Comment: thank for the reply. i have used union. got this error ` '#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNION SELECT * FROM `list_5`' at line 2' `


//// i used this command ` INSERT INTO `new_table` UNION SELECT * FROM `list_5`  `

Comment: @VidavalapatiAkhilesh `UNION` comes after the first select not before it. see this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/60b66/2/1